# Columbus's coccyges

Tags: riddle, knowledge, geography

> Calculate Christopher Columbus's coccyges, characterize Cyprus / Cuba / Crete. Count couplet's components, country's command central, Cairo, Chicago & Cebu.

Correct comeback comprises 10 characters.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pretty sure the clue is leading us to

> ONE [Columbus had one coccyx] ISLAND [Cyprus, Cuba, Crete] TWO [components in a couplet] CAPITAL [country's command central] CITIES [Cairo, Chicago and Cebu -- strictly Cebu City]

in which case the obvious 10-letter answer is

> HISPANIOLA.

Credit where it's due:

> I originally had "ONE COUNTRY TWO CAPITALS" and El-Guest, in comments, suggested breaking that last one up a little, a clear improvement.

Comment: As AHKieran pointed out, Chicago isn't the capital of anything (not even Illinois) but otherwise this answer seems convincing.

Comment: But Chicago *is* a [capital](https://chicago.cbslocal.com/2018/07/20/study-chicago-rat-capital-u-s/)

Comment: Personally, I think that the lines can be spread out leading to a clearer answer. Namely, Count couplet’s components = GJB; Country’s command central = PNCVGNY; Cairo, Chicago, and Cebu = PVGVRF. You wouldn’t have to wrangle with your classification of Chicago or Cebu in this case.

Comment: @El-Guest Ah, that's plausible. Will adjust. (Though I'm pretty sure "Cebu" should still be "Cebu City", strictly speaking.)

Comment: Completely correct! Checkmark comes correspondingly.

Answer (score 4):

Partial:

> I have answers for each section but have no idea how to put them together.

*Calculate Christopher Columbus's coccyges*

> coccyges is the plural of coccyx (the tail bone), of which Christopher Columbus would have had **ONE(1)**

*characterize Cyprus, Cuba or Crete*

> Each of these places are **islands**, so I would characterise them as such.

*Count couplet's components*

> A couplet comprises of **TWO(2)** components.

*country's command central, Cairo, Chicago and Cebu.*

> Cairo is in Egypt, Chicago is in the USA, and Cebu is in the Philippines. These have the ISO 3166 country codes of EG, US, and PH respectively (if that means anything). To me, command central would indicate the country's capital cities, Cairo is Egypt's capital, but Chicago is not even the capital of Illinois, let alone the entire US, and Cebu City is the capital of the Cebu province, but Manilla is the capital of the Philippines.